# I want to remove values from an arraylist, but I want to keep the original list

Tags: java, arraylist, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

Basically, I am trying to implement a drop-down filter wherby the user selects a name and the list updates. Therefore I need to reset the list back to its original form and then apply the filter.

This is what I have:

```
int size = list.size();
int count = 0;
ArrayList<Object> newList = new ArrayList<>();
newList = (ArrayList<Object>)list.clone();
for (int i=0; i<list.size();){
    if(!list.get(i).getForename().equals(forename)){
        list.remove(i);
    }
    else {
        i++;
    }
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Is there a way to temporarily delete a list, so that when i select a value everytime it updates?

Comment: There are far better ways to do this (namely, if you're making DB queries, have your database filter instead), but it depends on how you're building your data out.  Also, `Object` wouldn't have a method `getForename()`, so your example doesn't compile.

Comment: You can't reset a list. Make a copy that you can switch to anytime you want to reset the list to it's former state.

Comment: I am using an adapter for my `recyclerview` which is why I have to use the same list

Comment: How are you populating the list?

Comment: Through `volley`. I am retrieving values through `JSON`

Comment: Is there an answer to my question?